# Mixing time of three particle systems

Tags: reference-request, permutations, markov-chains

Is there anything known about mixing time of Markov chains for three particle systems?

It is [proved here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2005-357-08/S0002-9947-05-03610-X/S0002-9947-05-03610-X.pdf)
that the mixing time of an exclusion process is $\operatorname{O}(n)$. We can think if a exclusion process, a Markov chain on permutations of two particles $(0,1)$. I wonder if there is any result such as that for three particles.

Comment: This *might* be better suited to the [CS Stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) site.